# help IDing flowering mint

Tags: identification, mint

a garden on a campus near my home has a very prolific mint growing throughout it. today I noticed it was flowering! I'm really curious to know what type it is because the flowers look quite dissimilar to most variety examples I can find; they almost look like little small pairs of deep purple orchids, rather than big rods of clustered pink or whitish blooms.
The leaves are soft, textured, a little hairy, toothed edges, and smell like mint. they grow in pairs of two around the stem. The stem is green; there's no darker tinting anywhere on the plant. The plants are growing tall, around two feet or a bit more. They are growing in northwestern Ohio.
[image: purple mint flower]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Excellent photos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely a catmint, but which variety is the question. Given its height, it may be [Walker's Low](https://e54055a024bc6fb58d47-f7df714a3b816a175961a96ef2278d84.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/1649-Walkers-Low-Catmint.jpg) (and [here](https://www.raveplants.com/plant-selections/perennials/images/Nepeta-Walker%27s-Low.jpg)) (the "Low" in the name refers to a place, not a height). It's listed at two feet high by two to three feet spread.

Comment: that does look like it! and it explains why my cat has been so obsessed with the sprigs ive been drying. thanks!

Comment: An up-vote and accepted answer would be nice. :)